# UL and floating DIV: list text wraps but background color doesn't

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists, background-color

Need help with a floating `DIV` and a list. A `DIV` is floating to the right side of a page while list entries flow around it. The problem is that on applying background color to LI elements of the list the color stretches full width while text wraps on reaching DIV. How to make background color of LI's wrap like text does while keeping LI's display as blocks?

Here is the example code:

```html
<html>
<style>
  .mydiv {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 45px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
  }
  
  li {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="mydiv"></div>

  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `display: inline;` as follows

```
li
{
    background-color:cyan;
    display: inline;
}
```

EDIT:

Another way, assuming you can add a fixed with to your UL

```
ul
{
    width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Hm. This helped indeed but I probably was not clear enough on what I'm trying to achieve. I still want LI's to display as <b>blocks</b> but with background color wrapping exactly where text does - on reaching DIV. Is it possible to do this with CSS?

Comment: yup... there are many ways. One is to add a width to the UL (if its ok in your situation). I edited the answer with an example.

Comment: Adding width was one of the options I've considered and dropped because I have a flexible layout and can't expect container element of floating DIV and UL to be of the same width.

Comment: I see. I'll check more and get back to you (if there's no answer from anyone else)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the CSS to:

```
li {
    background-color:cyan;
    margin-right:45px;
}
```

then the `<li>` will end where the `<div class="mydiv">` ends. You could even set it to `margin-right:245px;`, which will cause the `<li>` to end at the left edge instead.

Comment: Well, not exactly what I was looking for as there can be no floated DIV at all at the right side of the page in my actual code and the right margin of LI's will look weird without a DIV. It seems that this problem doesn't have an (easy) solution. Okay, I'll try to find some formatting workaround myself.

Comment: Why does your question have a floated `<div>` if your actual code does not? I am confused! If you post your actual code then it gives other users a better chance of answering the question and you getting the answer you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about applying a margin on your ul tag

try this css and perhaps that brings you where you want to go. The div is not floating, so you need to decide if you really need it to be.

```
<style>
    .mydiv
    {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-left:45px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    }
    li
    {
    background-color:cyan;
    }
   ul{
    margin-right: 200px;
    }
</style>
```